# System of multiple nonlinear equations vs. system of linear equations with nonlinear constraints in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve in Python a system of 22 nonlinear equations with 22 variables x_1, ..., x_{22}. The system is linear on each variable, i.e., I only have products of diferent variables, never power of a single one.

To solve it, I am "linearizing" the problem by defining products of variables as a new variable. For instance, I can define x_{(1,22)}=x_1*x_{22}. The new version of the problem, of course, has infinite solutions. However, my ideia is to add the definition of the new variables as constraints. Is that possible? Is that a better approach for solving the problem, e.g., by solving the nonlinear equations directly?

Comment: Why don't you use https://math.stackexchange.com/, seems like a math problem.

Comment: you are not linearizing in this way, just changed its form

Comment: But I don't know how I could add the constraints in Python. That's why I thought of adding it here.